# Copy Multiple Files and Directories with ANT

Tags: java, ant

I have an Ant Script, using the ANT LIBRARY how can i copy multiple files/folders to multiple directories. I use a properties file which contains

```
FileToCopy = DestinationFolder
FolderToCopy = FolderDestination
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy a single file

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" tofile="mycopy.txt"/>
```

Copy a single file to a directory

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" todir="../some/other/dir"/>
```

Copy a directory to another directory

```
<copy todir="../new/dir">
   <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
 </copy>
```

Copy a set of files to a directory

```
<copy todir="../dest/dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir">
     <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
   </fileset>
</copy>

 <copy todir="../dest/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir" excludes="**/*.java"/>
 </copy>
```

examples from [copy ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information to [sergiofbsilva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317605/)s answer, because I was searching for such an example.

One can also specify multiple filesets in a single `copy` task.

Example:

```
<copy todir="${temp.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}"/>
  <fileset dir="${basedir}">
    <include name="log4j.xml"/>
    <include name="config.properties"/>
    <include name="kfatransfer.bat"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Tested with ant `1.10.6` on Windows.